# C# WebService return json

Tags: c#, json, post

I need to return a message from this web service bellow, but it has to be in json format. Is it possible to achieve this now?

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public response HelloWorld()
        {
            response obj = new response
            {
                message = "No fromFormat recieved.",
                success = false
            };

            return obj;
        }
    }

    public class response
    {
        public string message = "";
        public Boolean success = false;
    }
}
```

jQuery code:

```
//contentType: "application/json" if I add this line, response is undefined.
$('document').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://exampleUrl.com/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
    });
});
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <message>No fromFormat recieved.</message>
  <success>false</success>
</response>
```

Comment: [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] will not give you json format?

Comment: You can use Newtonsoft.Json package with Nuget and return JObject typed object http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: no :/ And I don't know why exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The followig statement returns a json response

```
string json = JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize({"results":[{"id":1,"value":"ABC","info":"ABC"},{"id":2,"value":"XYZ","info":"XYZ"});
return json;
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="WebApplication1">{"message":"No fromFormat recieved.","success":false}</string> 
this is response now.

Comment: if in you JQuery function you sadd a var like: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` what is the answer?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked. Thanks. But now I get this stranke json with "d" attribute name. {"d":{"__type":"WebApplication1.response","message":"No fromFormat recieved.","success":false}}

Comment: This is quite strange, let me show your c# return statement?

Comment: return statement is still the same as in code in question above. Returning whole object..

Comment: ok, maybe it comes from your `console.log`, try the following `console.log(data.message);`

Comment: then it is undefined.

Comment: Here we go...return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj); now this is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

use Newtonsoft.Json
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm

```
  public response HelloWorld()
            {
                response obj = new response
                {
                    message = "No fromFormat recieved.",
                    success = false
                };

                string Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
                return obj;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
public string HelloWorld()
        {
            response obj = new response
            {
                message = "No fromFormat recieved.",
                success = false
            };
            var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
          return jsondata.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct C# code:

```
public String HelloWorld()
{
    response obj = new response
    {
        message = "No fromFormat recieved.",
        success = false
    };

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
}
```

Correct jQuery code is:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://exampleUrl.com/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
    });
});
```

Response:

> {"message":"No fromFormat recieved.","success":false}